# Detect double error using Hamming code.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I have a sequence of bits 
$$
111011011110
$$
and need to detect two errors(without correction) using Hamming codes. Hamming codes contain a control bit in each $2^n$ position. Hence I should put this control bits in their positions.

$$
0010110011011110
$$

I've found a simple explanation of how to count the code for a sequence of bits. It says that each control bit responds for the following bits using these rules: First control bit responds for $2^n$ position and each following bit through $2^n$ . So the first bit responds for the first, third, fifth and etc. bits. The second control bit responds for 2nd, 3rd, 6th, 7th, 10th, 11th and etc. bits. Third control bit(which is on the 4th position) responds for 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 12th, 13th etc. bits. And so on. The value of each of the controls bits is counted as a modulo sum of the bits, which this control bit responds for.

Here is an illustration of what I mean:

[image]

Assuming this rule is right, the last 16th bit(after control bits addition) is not under the responsibility of any of the control bits.

So the question is: How can I detect double error(only detect, not correct) for the given sequence of bits using the Hamming code?

Comment: Your diagram seems to indicate a new codeword starts at position $16$ since the pattern repeats,. Thus, the first $15$ bits include $4$ **parity** bits (using the nomenclature that is standard in coding theory will help get better answers), and so you have what is called a $[15,11]$ Hamming code.  There is no way of detecting that two errors with this code.  In order to detect two errors, you need to modify your scheme so that the $16$th bit is a parity check on _all_ $15$ previous bits (including the parity bits at positions $1,2,4,8$, and the _next_ codeword starts at position $17$.

Comment: @Dilip, the code whose parity check matrix is the $4\times15$ matrix whose columns are all the nonzero 4-bit strings --- isn't that the $[15,11]$ Hamming code? And isn't its minimal distance $3$? So it should be able to detect (though not correct) $2$ errors, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson With a $[15,11]$ Hamming code (more generally, $[2^m-1,2^m-1-m]$ Hamming code) of minimum distance $3$, one can _detect_ that two **or fewer** errors have occurred. More generally, a code of minimum distance $d$ can detect all patterns of $d-1$ or fewer errors.  But if the Hamming code is also being used for error correction simultaneously (which is the most common case in textbooks), then two errors cannot be _detected_; the decoder will think it is a single error, and the decoder output will be the wrong codeword.  (continued)

Comment: @GerryMyerson The most common case in _practice_ is the use of the CRC-32 code in which the codewords are shortened codewords from a $[2^{32}-1,2^{32}-33]$ Hamming code, and only error detection is the only capability used; no error correction is attempted.  P.S. I assumed that the OP's question "How can I detect double error (only detect not correct)..." to mean that the OP wanted to correct single errors _and_ only detect, but not attempt to correct, double errors.

Comment: @innocent Are you really asking for the ability to distinguish between whether one or two errors occurred? All that is certain is that the code will not confuse a single or double error for a codeword. A parity check matrix will detect if only one or two errors are made, but it won't be able to distingush between them.

Comment: @rschwieb
The aim is to detect two errors(if they present). So the question is just how to detect these errors. I'm given a bit sequence, then i make two errors, and then just check that two errors are made(by counting Hamming code from the original bit sequence and comparing it with the Hamming code or error-containing bit sequence).

Comment: @innocent_rifle I still don't think that answers my question. A parity check matrix will reject any double error as a codeword. That is how to "detect these errors." However, if your real aim is to distinguish between single and double errors, I do not think the ordinary Hamming code has the capacity to separate them.

Comment: @Dilip, OP specifically asks, "How can I detect double error(only detect, not correct) for the given sequence of bits using the Hamming code?" OP says nothing about wanting to do any correction, of single errors or anything else.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, and that can be interpreted as saying "I want to detect that **two** errors have occurred, only detect, not correct..." and that is not possible with the Hamming code. One can detect that the received word is not a valid codeword and so one or more errors have occurred, but one _cannot_ say in _which_ instances of invalid received words two errors have occurred and in which instances one (or more than two) errors have occurred. All that can be said is that this received word is invalid, and so one or more errors have occurred.

Comment: Chiming in to support Dilip. You need the extended Hamming code with minimum distance four to detect that two errors have occurred. You can then rule out the possibility of a single error by the Hamming codes failure to correct.

Comment: To make it absolutely clear. There is obviously nothing wrong with @Gerry Myerson's reading comprehension. I'm just so used to the coding theory parlance, where you use phrases like "detect all the error patterns of weight at most two" to indicate what Gerry described. That meaning is relevant, for example, in selecting an appropriate CRC-polynomial, and you are only interested in verifying that the received sequence of bits is a legal codeword. OTOH when you phrase it like "detect all double errors", you really want to ascertain that at least two errors have occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you cannot find out if exactly two errors appeared: The Hamming code is a perfect code of minimum distance $3$. Thus, if you have a codeword $c$ which after two errors is transmitted as the codeword $e$, there is always another codeword $c'$ with differs from $e$ only in a single position (since in the perfect Hamming code, the Hamming balls of radius $1$ centered at the codewords cover the Hamming space).

For detecting if a transmitted word $e$ is erroneous, you can apply the standard method for linear codes: Take a parity-check matrix $H$ of the Hamming code. Then compute the product $He$. If it is not the zero vector, you know for sure that $e$ is not a codeword, which means that there is at least one error. By the minimum distance $3$ of the Hamming code, you will detect all cases where a single or two errors appeared (but you don't know the exact number), and some of the cases with more errors.

Comment: that explanation worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is handled well by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#Hamming_codes_with_additional_parity_.28SECDED.29), which states:

Hamming codes have a minimum distance of 3, which means that the decoder can detect and correct a single error, but it cannot distinguish a double bit error of some codeword from a single bit error of a different codeword. Thus, they can detect double-bit errors only if correction is not attempted.

To remedy this shortcoming, Hamming codes can be extended by an extra parity bit.

Comment: @user73324: This is good information. It would be better to add this to the answer than in a comment.